# Question on Taylor Polynomials

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Can someone please tell me how to go about this question? It's got me confused.

> Using the Taylor polynomial $P_{3}(x)$ of $e^x$, find a Taylor polynomial $P_{8}(x)$ for $x^{2}e^{-x^{2}}$. Use that to estimate the following integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}e^{-x^{2}}dx.$$

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Just take $P_3(x)$ and plug in $-x^2$ for $x$ and then raise all powers of $x$ by two.  Then you have $P_8(x)$ which as a polynomial is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well first off you'd start off with the definition of a taylor polynomial, and we'll pick ours at a=0.

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+f'''(a)\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}...$$

Now let's figure out the things we need to plug in.

$$\left(e^{x}\right)^{n}=e^{x}$$

where n is the nth derivative.

and

$$e^{0}=1$$

Plug it in what we found and you will get:

$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}...$$

Now since we want $P_3$ we'll take up to and and including the term of degree 3.

Now to find a composition (i.e. $e^{-x^2})$ all you need to do is plug in -$-x^2$ into the polynomial we found above.

To compute the integral, plug in the polynomial we found with  $(-x^2)$ plugged in, multiply by $x^2$ and integrate!

........................

Answer (score 8):

By Taylor,
$$P_3(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6$$ so that
$$x^2P_3(-x^2)=x^2-x^4+\frac{x^6}2-\frac{x^8}6.$$

As

$$\int_0^1 x^kdx=\frac1{k+1},$$ the final answer is

$$\frac13-\frac15+\frac1{14}-\frac1{54}.$$

---

It is an easy matter to see that the general term is

$$\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+3)k!}.$$

I couldn't resist to show the approximations to the true function (in blue) from polynomials $\color{green}{P_3}$, $P_4$ and $\color{magenta}{P_5}$.

[image]

Comment: why does P4 seem more accurate than P5??

Comment: @tuskiomi: because I swapped the colors. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$
P_3(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6
$$
Note that $P_8(x) = x^2 P_3(-x^2)$
$$
P_8(x) = x^2 \left( 1 -x^2 + x^4/2 -x^6/6 \right) = x^2 - x^4 + x^6/2 - x^8/6
$$
Now you can simply integrate $P_8(x)$ using standard anti-derivative of polynomials !

Answer (score 1):

$e^x = \sum \frac {x^n}{n!}\\
x^2 e^{-x^2} = \sum \frac {(-1^n)x^{2n+2}}{n!}\\
\int x^2 e^{-x^2} = \sum \frac {(-1^n)x^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)n!}$

Comment: I believe you're supposed to use the Taylor polynomial, not the Taylor series.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: with a finite number of terms, these are indeed good ol' polynomials.

Comment: I think it's the reason your answer is not getting the votes the others are.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: who are you talking to ?

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: no, it's not.

Comment: @GregoryGrant. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You guys sure have a lot of time on your hands.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: welcome to the club!